# How to find analog voltage period and average value of connected signal?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller

I'm using STM32 and i need to find analog voltage period and average value of connected signal which is connected to PC0. I need to read the analog voltage and find the period of signal. I need to write a c code.

Comment: Get an oscilloscope.

Comment: i need to write a c code

Comment: Go ahead, that would help in making your question on-topic.    Show your attempt; this is not a free coding service.

Comment: You miss understood me, sir. I don't want to code. I want to learn how can i do this with just coding.

Comment: Find the peaks (or the zero crossings) and measure the time between them.

Comment: You should study some signal proccessing math. For example; sampling, digital filters, calculus. It's not all about code, you must know the math behind it.